# Converting input of State to the abbreviation

Tags: c++, string, user-input, sanitization

I am working on a personal C++ project and one of the features is to save contact information. When it comes to the address I want the state to save in its  abbreviation format.

I am working on a method that will accept a string input of the full name of the state and return a string value of the 2 character state abbreviation. That being said I have been brainstorming with some friends as to the best way to do this. As of right now I have finished the states that begin with 'A'; but before I go through the other 47 states I wanted to broaden my brainstorming by asking this question. If there a "better" or more efficient way to accomplish this? Please look at my function so far.

```
    std::string Address::formatStateInput(std::string stateInput){
        char firstLetter = toupper(stateInput.at(0)); //makes first character capital for easy checking
        if(firstLetter == 'A'){
        char letterToCheck = toupper(stateInput.at(3)); //makes fourth character capital for easy checking
            //Alabama
            if (letterToCheck == 'B'){
                return "AL";    
            }
            //Alaska
            else if (letterToCheck == 'S'){
                return "AK";
            }
            //Arizona
            else if (letterToCheck == 'Z'){
                return "AZ";
            }
            else{
                return "NULL";
            }
        }
        else{return "NULL";}
    }
```

Comment: Give us an example of the string you pass to the method.

Comment: The string that would pass through the method would be the name of one of the 50 United States (haven't got far enough to accept all countries) such as "Alabama".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use an `std::map` (or `std::unordered_map`).

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> abbrs;

abbrs["Alabama"] = "AL";
abbrs["Alaska"] = "AK";
abbrs["Arizona"] = "AZ";
// ...
```

Then to look up a state's abbreviation, you'd do something like:

```
auto pos = abbrs.find(user_input_state_name);
if (pos == abbrs.end())
    error_invalid_state_name(user_input_state_name);
else
    abbreviation = *pos;
```

Note that in a typical case, you probably don't want to really hard-code all the state names and abbreviations into your source code. You probably want to have the names and abbreviations in an external configuration file.

Comment: With this solution the input would have to be formatted perfectly with the first letter capital and the remaining characters lowercase though.

Comment: @Juken: Yes -- you normally want to take care of that separately (though it may be easier to opt for all lower-case, for example)

Comment: True. I guess that would also come in handy if I need the full state name later also.

Comment: A problem with this is it doesn't handle mispellings and typos. The op's approach could be coded in such a way to minimize this